# Objects and variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok so imagine I have the following object

```
var House= function(){
    var color = "#0000FF";
}
```

Then I add the following method:

```
House.prototype.drawHouse = function(){
    document.write("House " + this.color);
    // ^^ How do I reference the color property of the object?
}
```

How is the best way to reference the color attribute from the drawHouse method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot.

`var color` is a local variable, whose visibility scope is only limited by the anonymous function body.

You need to implement it like:

```
var House= function(){
    this.color = "#0000FF";
}
```

And after that you'll be able to access it via `this.color` in a `drawHouse()`

Comment: +1 thanks for the insight. Not sure why the question was downvoted.